# Download with File Explorer "save as" Window

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to download an image on the user's File Explorer when clicking on an image. But I want the File Explorer to open, where the user can choose a folder, where the file should be downloaded in.

that is the code I tried, which works for normal downloads in browser, without File Explorer opening:

```
const filepath = decodeURIComponent(req.query.filepath).replace(/\//g, "\\");
  const filename = path.basename(filepath);
  const fileType = path.extname(filepath).slice(1);

  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `inline; filename="${filename}"`);
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", `image/${fileType}`);

  res.sendFile(filename, { root: path.join(__dirname, "../images") }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next();
    }
  });
```

Comment: The [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) here is explicitly `inline`, did you mean to use `attachment` instead?

Comment: From browser js you can use  [MDN: showSaveFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker).